# Return a value adjacent to the first negative number in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a retirement calculator and I'd like to add a cell showing how long into retirement my savings will last. So I want to have it display the date (column A) that my balance (column C) first drops below $0 so I know how long different saving/spending rates will last me into retirement.

Edit: whoops, found the answer in a post that I thought was only asking for the cell value itself. I got it: =INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(0,$B:$B,-1)+1)

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? (You are allowed to answer your own question.)  That will help others with the same question and save time for people who want to help and don't see that the question has already been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by OP in edit just putting it here so this question isn't *unanswered*:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(0,$C:$C,-1)+1)
```

note that the search column is C and the value is returned from A as requested by OP.